# Ionic 2 : importing custom components / modules with absolute path fails

Tags: angular, typescript, import, webpack, ionic2

I'm developing an ionic 2 app with these dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-rc.4",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.47",
    "typescript": "2.0.6",
    "electron": "^1.4.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "0.0.2",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.21",
    "codelyzer": "^2.0.0-beta.1"
 }
```

The structure of the app is this one:

```
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.json
src
  app
     app.module.ts
  pages
     home
       home.page.ts
     login
  modules
```

When I import a module / Component / Class or whatever from

> app.module.ts

using relative paths, theres no problem:

```
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home.page';
```

I prefer to use absolute paths, but i can't find the way to use them.  I have tried to setup typescript tsconfig.json like this:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": ".",

     "paths": {
      "*": [
        "*",
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
  }
```

and importing like this:

```
import { HomePage } from 'pages/home/home.page';
```

but the typescript compiler gives me this error inside the IDE ( `"Cannot find module 'pages/home/home.page'`

When executing the ionic app (with `ionic serve`) this is the error I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module "pages/home/home.page"
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:81745:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:104718:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:66:18
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:69:10
```

The idea I would like to setup is to use absolute paths starting from src/ and then using the folders structure like a namespace path:

So if the path of the component is `root/src/pages/home/home.page`

Import components using this:

```
import { HomePage } from 'pages/home/home.page';
import { LoginPage } from 'pages/login/login.page';
```

The HomePage component is this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home-page', 
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html'  
})

export class HomePage {

    // Array of pages for main menu
    pages: Array<{ component: any, name:string }>;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        // set our app's pages
        this.pages = [
            { component: LoginPage, name: 'Login' },
            { component: SyncPage, name: 'Sync Service' },
            { component: FilesPage, name: 'Selecting a file' },
        ];
    }

    gotoPage(page) {
        this.navCtrl.push(page.component);
    }

}
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try to set `"baseUrl"` pointing to your `src` folder in `tsconfig.json` ?

Comment: Yup, as @n00dl3 mentioned, `baseUrl` should be `"./src"`; right now it points to your project root, not app root (`src/`). `import { HomePage } from 'src/pages/home/home.page';` should work with your current setup.

Comment: Hi guys, neither of both solutions work, I mean, baseUrl :"." with import { HomePage } from 'src/pages/home/home.page';   nor "baseUrl": "./src" with  import { HomePage } from 'pages/home/home.page';

Comment: Post HomePage class

Comment: @misha130, class added in the main question.

Comment: Try to remove path from tsconfig and add   "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],

Comment: It's done, with no success. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Might be a problem of webpack? I have added the error I get when executing the app. It's bundled on build/main.js

Comment: I mean, maybe I must use a webpack resolver...

Comment: Don't forget to up your angular version to 2.2.1. Just for safety

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.
On some preliminar test what seems to be working for me is a slight change on your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "*": [
    "/src/*"
  ]
}
```

edit: it works on browser, but tscompiler tells that it can't find the modules :|